# Extract information between strings from a file and write to csv

Tags: python, regex, string, csv, nested

I would like to extract some info (between strings e.g. oldtime: ... oldtime!>) from a text file and write it in a CSV file.  My input text file is like this:

```
=======================
oldtime:

 hours:1:hours!>

 minutes:12:minutes!> 

oldtime!>

newtime:

 hours:15:hours!>

 minutes:17:minutes!> 

newtime!>


oldtime:

 hours:11:hours!>

 minutes:22:minutes!> 

oldtime!>  


newtime:

 hours:5:hours!>

 minutes:17:minutes!> 

newtime!>  

==========================
```

I started with this but I can not go any further.

```
with open(inputfile, 'r') as f, open(outputfile.cvs, 'a') as f1:
    f1.write("oldtime; newtime \n")
    for row in f:
        if "oldtime:" in str(row):
            temp = re.split(r'(@oldtime[\n\r]|[\n\r]@oldtime!>)', str(row))

            ???

        if "newtime:"  in str(row):
            temp = re.split(r'(@newtime[\n\r]|[\n\r]@newtime!>)', str(row))
```

I would like to get as an output a csv-file like this

```
oldtime  newtime
01:12     15:17
11:22     05:17
```

Could you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution close to the Rakesh solution assuming your file has always the same structure (oldtime -> hour -> min -> newtime -> hour -> min ...).

1. **Extract** all the number of a string with regex formula: `match = re.findall(r'\d+', str_file)`
2. Convert this list by joining `hours` and `minutes`: `dates = [i+ ":" + j for i, j in zip(match[::2], match[1::2])]`
3. **Create a `dataframe`** using the `pandas` module
4. **Export** the data

Here the code:

```
# Import module
import pandas as pd

with open("../temp.txt", 'r') as f:
    # Read file as a string
    str_file = f.read()

    # Extract all numbers
    match = re.findall(r'\d+', str_file)
    print(match)
    # ['1', '12', '15', '17', '11', '22', '5', '17']

    # create dates
    dates = [i+ ":" + j for i, j in zip(match[::2], match[1::2])]
    print(dates)
    # ['1:12', '15:17', '11:22', '5:17']

    # create dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame({"oldtime": dates[::2],
                        "newtime": dates[1::2]})
    print(df)
    #    oldtime  newtime
    # 0    1:12   15:17
    # 1   11:22    5:17

    # Export the data
    df.to_csv("output.csv", index= False)
```

[image]

EDIT 1:
Assuming than the `oldtime` and `newtime` blocks can be swiped. Here I read the file line per line and categorise the `oldtime` and `newtime` in a dictionary. There are many `slice` but working on my test file.

```
# Import module
import pandas as pd

with open("../temp.txt", 'r') as f:
    # Read file as a string
    list_split = ["oldtime:", "newtime:"]
    dates = {"oldtime:": [], "newtime:": []}
    line = f.readline().rstrip('\n')

    while True:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        print([line])
        if line in list_split:
            key = line

            hours = f.readline().rstrip('\n').split(":")[1]
            minutes = f.readline().rstrip('\n').split(":")[1]

            dates[key].append(hours+':'+minutes)

        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break

    print(dates)
    # {'oldtime:': ['1:12', '11:22'], 'newtime:': ['15:17', '5:17']}

    # create dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame({"oldtime": dates["oldtime:"],
                       "newtime": dates["newtime:"]})
    print(df)
    #    oldtime  newtime
    # 0    1:12   15:17
    # 1   11:22    5:17

    # Export the data
    df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

EDIT 2:

```
import pandas as pd

with open("../temp.txt", 'r') as f:
    # Read file as a string
    list_split = ["oldtime:", "newtime:"]
    dates = {"oldtime": [], "newtime": []}
    line = f.readline().rstrip('\n')

    while True:
        # Ignore blank lines
        if ("oldtime:" in line) or ("newtime:" in line):
            # Process new "oldtime" or "newtime" block

            # Class : either "oldtime" or "newtime"
            class_time = line.replace(" ", "").rstrip('\n')[:-1]

            # Default hour - minute values
            hours = "24"
            minutes = "60"

            # Read next line
            line = f.readline().rstrip('\n')

            # While block not ended 
            while class_time + "!>" not in line:
                # If hour in line: update hour
                if 'hour' in line:
                    hours = line.split(":")[1]
                # If minute in line: update minute
                elif 'minute' in line:
                    minutes = line.split(":")[1]

                # Read next line
                line = f.readline().rstrip('\n')
            # End block

            # Add block read to dictionary
            dates[class_time].append(hours+':'+minutes)

        # Read next line
        line = f.readline()
        # If end of file: exit
        if not line:
            break

    # create dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame({"oldtime": dates["oldtime"],
                       "newtime": dates["newtime"]})

    # Export the data
    df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Hope that Help !

Comment: Thank you Alexandre but the point is that I need to have a clear separation between the oldtime and newtime data sets as this is just an example and the data sets can appear in another sequence.Thank you.

Comment: @Lilly The Edit read the file line per line and add the `hours` - `minutes` based on a dictionary key. Even if blocks are swiped, it's still working.

Comment: @ Alexandre.B. Thank you so much Alexandre! The "EDIT 1" is helping me a lot. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad to help you ! Cheers :)

Comment: Do you have lines like `hours::hours!>` or no lines at all ? How do your problematic line looks like ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.   I have for instance some empty lines e.g. no line hour. So my idea was each time I have a void line for the hours to put 24. So I tried to add this to your code:      temp = f.readline().rstrip('\n').split(":")
            #print temp
            if temp[0] == " hours":                       
                hours = temp[1]
            else:    
                hours = 24
            
            minutes = f.readline().rstrip('\n').split(":")[1]   but it is not working. Could you please help with this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195343/discussion-between-alexandre-b-and-lilly).

Comment: OK i go to the chat.

Comment: MANY thnaks for you help Alexandre B. Edit 2 work perfect!

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach using Regex and `csv` module.

**Ex:**

```
import re
import csv

with open(filename) as infile, open(filename_1, "w") as outfile:
    data = infile.read()
    hrs = re.findall(r"hours:(\d+):hours", data)       #Get all HRS
    mins = re.findall(r"minutes:(\d+):minutes", data)  #Get All Mins
    data = zip(hrs, mins)

    writer = csv.writer(outfile)                       #Write CSV
    writer.writerow(["oldtime", "newtime"])            #Header
    for m, n in zip(data[0::2], data[1::2]):         
        writer.writerow([":".join(m), ":".join(n)])    #Write OLD time & New Time
```

Comment: Rakesh Thank you a lot, but the point is that my oldtime, newtime set of values are not always one after another so I need a clear/ direct distinction betwneen the Oldtime  and the newtime set of values ...

Comment: Can you post an example and output for that?

Comment: For example my input file could look like this: oldtime:

 hours:1:hours!>

 minutes:12:minutes!> 

oldtime!>                                                                                                       
oldtime:

 hours:13:hours!>

 minutes:12:minutes!> 

oldtime!>
newtime:

 hours:11:hours!>

 minutes:12:minutes!> 

newtime!>, So I need a clear separation of the set of data starting with oldtime: and finishing with oldtime!>  and the set of data starting with newtime: and finishing with newtime!>, THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

great question :).

Here's a simple solution I did, delaminating the string on the ":" character, turning the number strings into integers, combining them with :, and then writing them to a csv.

Here is the code:

```
import csv
f = "data.txt"
with open('data.txt','r') as f:
    data = f.read()
data = data.split(sep=':')
nums = []
for i in data:
    try:
        nums.append(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        pass

times = []
for i in range(len(nums)):
    if i%2 ==0:
        times.append(str(nums[i]) + ":" + str(nums[i+1]))
num_rows = len(times)/2

with open('time_data.csv','w+',newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['oldtime','newtime'])
    for i in range(len(times)):
        if i%2==0:
            writer.writerow([times[i],times[i+1]])
```

After reading Rakesh's answer, I wrote this:

```
import re
import csv
list_i = ''
file_name = 'data.txt'
file_name1 = 'data_1.txt'
with open(file_name,'r') as f, open(file_name1,'w',newline='') as f1:
    data = f.read()
    list_1 = re.findall(r'hours:\d+:hours',data)
    list_2 = re.findall(r'minutes:\d+:minutes',data)
    for i in list_1:
        list_i += i  
    list_2_i = ''
    for i in list_2:
        list_2_i += i 
    list_1 = re.findall(r'\d+',list_i)
    list_2 = re.findall(r'\d+',list_2_i)
    data = []
    for i in range(len(list_1)):
        if i%2==0:
            data.append([str(list_1[i]) + ':' + str(list_2[i]),str(list_1[i+1]) + ':' + str(list_2[i+1])])
    writer = csv.writer(f1)
    writer.writerow(['oldtime','newtime'])
    for i in data:
        writer.writerow(i)
```

Also @Rakesh your code returned the error:
TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable
Is there a way to fix this? :)

Comment: Thank you @DBless. The solution that works for my case is the one of Alexandre.B.

Comment: You're welcome, I realize I didnt even answer the full questions becoause oldtime and newtime can be swithced... oh well :)